# How to retrieve a specific value from a Table with SQL in VBA

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, combobox

I am trying to access a **specific** value (`CompanyNr`) from the `TABLE 1` and store it into a variable. To later use it to access the Company name from `TABLE 2`

**MY TABLE EXAMPLES:**

```
TABLE 1 (Contacts):
ID , CompanyNr , Contact


TABLE 2 (Companies):
CompanyNr , Company
```

I have a `ComboBox` for Contacts. And I when I select someone from the `ComboBox`, I want to automaticly filter out Companies in which the selected Contact works.

I have tried like this:

**MY CODE:**

```
CompNr = "SELECT [Contacts].[ID], [Contacts].[CompanyNr] FROM Contacts " & _
            "WHERE [Contacts].[ID] = " & ContactNrCombo.Value & " ORDER BY [Contact];"

MsgBox "Company Nr:" & CompNr

sq11 = "SELECT [Companies].[CompanyNr], [Companies].[Company] FROM Companies " & _
        "WHERE [Companies].[CompanyNr] = " & CompNr & "ORDER BY [Company]; "
```

**But the MsgBox says:**

```
CompNr = SELECT [Contacts].[ID], [Contacts].[CompanyNr] FROM Contacts                         WHERE [Contacts].[ID] = 255 ORDER BY [Contact]
```

Yet I need to get a certain value for CompanyNr (like 50 for example) so that I can use it in my other SQL Statement to filter from `TABLE 2`.

*I am new to SQL statements, I just found the above one as an example on internet and thought I could use it. But it didn`t work well.*

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following,

```
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

con.Open "Provider=..."    'Your Connectionstring

rs.Open "SELECT [Contacts].[ID], [Contacts].[CompanyNr] FROM Contacts " & _
            "WHERE [Contacts].[ID] = " & ContactNrCombo.Value & " ORDER BY [Contact]", con, 1,3

'Assuming there is only one company number per contact
rs.MoveFirst
CompNr = rs.Fields("CompanyNr").Value

rs.Open "SELECT [Companies].[CompanyNr], [Companies].[Company] FROM Companies " & _
        "WHERE [Companies].[CompanyNr] = " & CompNr & "ORDER BY [Company]", con, 1,3

'If you want to paste the second sql query in excel use this

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I found a smoother solution - I used DLookup !